# How to pause Python while Tkinter window is open?

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, pausing-execution

I'm writing a program that sometimes encounters an error. When it does, it pops up a Tkinter dialog asking the user whether to continue. It's a more complicated version of this:

```
keep_going = False
KeepGoingPrompt(keep_going)
if not keep_going:
    return
```

The prompt sets `keep_going` to `True` or leaves it `False`.
Problem is, the code seems to continue while `KeepGoingPrompt` is open. I tried storing a reference to the `prompt` and adding a loop like

```
while prompt:
    time.sleep(1)
```

but python gets stuck in the loop and freezes. 
Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the tkMessageBox class to pop up a question dialog that is modal and won't return until the user clicks a button. See [the Tkinter book](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm) for details.

Comment: I tried that, but can't really tell if it's working because it seems to have caused some other odd bugs. But that's probably just something else in my code gone wrong. :(

Comment: Are you able to describe these bugs? It might give some indication as to whether they're related to the dialog call; since tkMessageBox is essentially a very simple wrapper for the Windows MessageBox API call I'd say it's unlikely that it's a problem with the call itself.

Comment: Well, fixed the error I was having. But now there's a new (maybe simpler?) one: the messagebox just gets skipped, same as my original dialog.

Comment: OK, pressing enter submits the comment. Good to know. Anyway, I fixed it. Instead of storing the result of tkMessageBox(), I just used "if not tkmessageBox(): return", and that seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you running your code inside IDLE? It might be responsible for making the dialogue non-blocking while it really should be blocking.

2) If running outside IDLE does not help, look for tkinter/dialogue options which specify whether behavior is blocking or non-blocking

Comment: Not IDLE, but I am running inside an experimental program with sort of a non-standard python interpreter in it. There could easily be something wacky in there. :)